# AngularJS - How can I read the value of a model defined in an isolate scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to use an isolate scope in a directive; I am trying to read the value of a model specified in an attribute.  So my directive is used like this:

```
<div mydirective="" mydirective-data="MyJson" />
```

In a controller, I am assigning a value to `$scope.MyJson`.  My directive should pick it up, but doesn't.

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       data: '&mydirectiveData',
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         console.log(scope.data);
         }
     }
   }
);
```

Note that I need to use an isolate scope.  I have also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsAbT/1/) with this problem in it.  (Remember to open the console)

I expect to see the value of `MyJson`, but am seeing nothing instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `&` within the scope with =, and it would get you the object. If you are using `&` use `scope.data()`

Comment: I changed the `&` to `=`, in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsAbT/4/), but nothing is being logged to console. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Shah, yes, you were missing `<body ng-app="MyApp">`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsAbT/6/)

Comment: @Shah it's a problem of fiddle, see this one [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/smQXjT) works

Answer (score 1):

I would write my directive this way:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     scope: {
       mydirectiveData: '='
     },
     link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         console.log(scope.mydirectiveData);
         }
     }
   }
);
```

Comment: I tried this - see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsAbT/3/) - but the console isn't logging anything.

Comment: @Shah, you didn't complete the set-up process. Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XsAbT/5/)